# Laravel Error: "Trying to get property of non-object"

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have a table what populates from database:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('main')
@parent
<table border=1 align=center;>
<tr><td rowspan=10><img src="media/productimg/question.jpg" width=250px></td>
<th>Márka</th><td colspan=3>{{ $productdetails->brand }}</td></tr>
<tr><th>Beszállító</th><td colspan=3>{{ $productdetails->supplier }}</td></tr>
<tr><th>{{ $productdetails->type }}</th>
<th colspan=3>{{ $productdetails->name }}</th></tr>
<tr><th>Nettó beszerzési ár</th><td>{{ $productdetails->wholeprice }} Ft</td>
<th rowspan=2>Ár</th><td rowspan=2>{{ $productdetails->price }} Ft</td></tr>
<tr><th>Bruttó beszerzési ár</th><td>{{ $productdetails->wholeprice }} Ft</td>
<tr><th>Vonalkód</th><td>{{ $productdetails->barcode }}</td><th>Raktáron</th><td>{{ $productdetails->count }} {{ $productdetails->dimension }}</td></tr>
<tr><th>Elhelyezkedés</th><td>{{ $productdetails->whereis }} {{ $productdetails->whereis2 }}</td><th>Küszöb</th><td>{{ $productdetails->threshold }} {{ $productdetails->dimension }}</td></tr>
<tr><th>Utolsó rendelés</th><td> NA </td>
<th>Utolsó vásárlás</th><td> NA </td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=5><a href="stock_productimageupload.php"><button class="button">Kép szerkesztése</button></a>
<a href="stock_productupdate.php"><button class="button">Termék szerkesztése</button></a>
<a href="stock_productcountupdate.php"><button class="button">Mennyiség szabályozása</button></a></td></tr>
</table>
@endsection
```

And I got this error:

> ErrorException in 20d205ed160f36c734b8252e44ac81bfa0977988.php line 6:
>   Trying to get property of non-object

If I replace the table with

```
<?php print_r($productdetails);?>
```

I got the the array with the good values.

What going wrong?

Comment: If you have array - why do you use `->`?

Comment: It's my first project in Laravel and the tutorial show this method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was: `{{ $productdetails[0]->type }}`

Thanks for @rahul_m for his answer:

> Once check the structure of array it is having 0th index first,
>
> You should get it like,
>
> `{{$product[0]->brand}}`
>
> OR
>
> `$product = DB::table("inventory")->where("barcode", $id)->first(); //`
>   `and get data as echo $product->brand;`
>
> Give it a try, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

You are saying that the array will show as it should be.

You could try for example:
`{{ $productdetails['type'] }}` instead of `{{ $productdetails->type }}`

But please post the result of the `print_r($productdetails)` function so that we can see whats wrong with the code.

Comment: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 1 [barcode] => 01233 [brand] => Ismeretlen [supplier] => 1 [type] => Építésianyag [name] => Homok [img] => homok.jpg [wholeprice] => 3000 [price] => 5500 [VAT] => 3 [whereis] => U [whereis2] => 1 [count] => 8 [dimension] => m3 [threshold] => 1 [lastsell] => [lastbuy] => [lastchange] => 2017-02-23 20:56:46 [register] => ) )

Comment: My guess is that your `$productdetails` is from an Eloquent `get()` method (or maybe `get()->toArray()` method). If you are using that, it means you have an **array** of **objects**, pretty clear from the dump you added. You either use `first()` instead of `get()` (if it's suitable in your controller) or you should use `$productdetalis[0]->barcode` in your view (which is ugly).

Comment: If it helps: the controller look like this:
class ProductDetailsController extends Controller
{
    public function productdetails($id){
 $productdetails = DB::select('select * FROM inventory WHERE barcode = ?', [$id]);;
 return view('productdetails',['productdetails'=>$productdetails]);
 }
} The ID comes from the URL

Comment: Try to consider the Eloquent way i.e. App\Inventory::where('barcode', '=', $id)->first(); It should then work in your view.